# Shared installed packages between official Skobbler app and app using the SDK

Tags: android, skmaps

Is there a possibility to share the downloaded Packages from Skobbler across the official Skobbler app (if installed) and an app that integrates the Skobbler SDK? So if the user already downloaded some packages in the Skkobbler App he has those packages synced with the packages in the other App integration the SDK. Same vice versa. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Legally, you should clear up this scenario with them (dev@skobbler.com)
2. Technically - address 1 and then they will inform you on which are your options.